# REST API using Nodejs Mongoose Express

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

```
  {
  "_id": "58be5a4a031372098578b1d6",
  "name": "A",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "username": "A.a",
  "password": "$2a$05$GAF1hP91EowKUTKr14ASL.MRd2lOjotfOgVlEghwnqctNcIe5seNW",
  "latitude": 12,
  "longitude": 72,
  "profilePic": "images/A.png",
  "__v": 9,
  "isBuddyEnabled": true,
  "friendRequests": [
    {
      "friendId": "58be7aa0c204cb134068975d",
      "isAccepted": true
    },
    {
      "friendId": "58bf8cb4c26d5811b188a600",
      "isAccepted": false
    }
  ],
  "friends": [
    "58be7aa0c204cb134068975d"
  ],
  "networkContacts": [
    {
      "profession": "doctor"
    }
  ],
  "interests": [
    "sports",
    "music"
  ]
}
```

I have the above json for a single user , now i need the array of such json with all info whose  friendRequest isAccepted is false which means these requests are pending for him,
for eg: when i hit api/requests/58be5a4a031372098578b1d6 => i have to get info of id 58bf8cb4c26d5811b188a600

till now i was able to retreive the ids whose request was not accepted via following query

```
app.post('/api/users/requests/:id'function(req,res){User.find({"_id":req.params.id})
  .find({"friendRequests.isAccepted":false},function(err,callback){}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array filter to pop out the subdocument in array based on the filter

```
User.find({"_id":req.params.id}, function (err, user) {

  var friendRequests = user.friendRequests.filter(function (fr) {
    return fr.isAccepted == false;
  }).pop();

  console.log(friendRequests); //logs { "friendId": "58bf8cb4c26d5811b188a600", "isAccepted": false
});
```

Comment: this i have achieved but i need to get whole json of friendId whose isAccepted is false

Comment: also for the above code it throws " Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
"